# Performing GET with JSON data using NSDictionary

Tags: ios, json, httprequest

I am trying to get this data using nsdictionary. My data looks like this:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Items": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "CorrectAnswer": "sample string 3",
      "Difficulty": 4,
      "CategoryId": 5,
      "CategoryName": "sample string 6",
      "AccountId": 7
    },
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "PicUrl": "sample string 2",
      "CorrectAnswer": "sample string 3",
      "Difficulty": 4,
      "CategoryId": 5,
      "CategoryName": "sample string 6",
      "AccountId": 7
    }
  "StartTime": "2013-10-07T00:24:22.0048045+00:00"
}
```

**this is what tried:**

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"playSegue" sender:self];

    NSString *GameId;
    NSNumber *ID;
    NSURL *PictureURL;
    NSString *ans1;
    NSString *ans2;
    NSString *ans3;
    NSString *ans4;
    NSArray *answers = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4, nil];
    NSString *correctAnswer;
    NSString *difficulty;
    NSString *categoryID;
    NSString *categoryName;
    NSNumber *accountID;
    NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:ID,PictureURL,answers,correctAnswer,categoryID,categoryName,accountID, nil];

    NSDictionary *result = [self requestWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"someurlhere"] Method:@"GET"
                                            Data:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                  GameId,@"GameId",
                                                  items, @"Items",
                                                  nil]
                                           Parse:YES];
    NSLog(@"the result is %@",result);


}


-(NSDictionary *)requestWithPath:(NSString *)path
                              Method:(NSString *)requestMethod
                                Data:(NSDictionary *)requestData
                               Parse:(BOOL)parse
    {
        if(path)        NSLog(@"%@", path);
        if(requestData) NSLog(@"%@", requestData);

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", path] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:requestMethod.uppercaseString];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

        if(requestData && [NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:requestData])
        {
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requestData options:0 error:&error];

            [request setHTTPBody:data];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        }

        NSURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:NULL];

        if(responseData)
            NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

        if(parse && responseData)
        {
            NSError *serializationError = nil;
            return [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&serializationError];
        }
        else if (responseData)
            return @{@"string": [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]};

        return nil;
    }
```

**Console result**

```
2013-10-06 19:01:16.477 FlickRest[41610:a0b] someurlhere
2013-10-06 19:01:16.478 FlickRest[41610:a0b] {
}
2013-10-06 19:01:17.186 FlickRest[41610:a0b] the result is (null)
```

**My Question**

Aside from not getting the result that I want, I believe I am not doing this in a right way. Could someone point out my mistake or suggest a way how I can convert the JSON data properly? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question. What exactly are you asking? The data you posted is a dictionary, just use it as such.

Comment: @PeterFoti, I edit the question. Thank you for taking time to look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)
And try use debug.

PS. Your a code is incorrect a lot.

Comment: thank you for responding. Are you talking about the way I try to store data or request with path method?Could you be more specific?

Comment: I am not sure if you read the code but that is what I am doing with the requestWithPath method and calling it as [self requestWithPath... The way I requested works fine for simple data. I am having problems with the part where I need do the mapping of complex objects(ids,urls,possible answers, and so on) which is why I asked this question in the first place.

Comment: firstly: "GET" methods request not support Body.
secondly: Always create NSError objects for catch errors.

Comment: Content-Length needs for POST request if you transfer files

Comment: Try Comment this lines: //        [request setHTTPBody:data];
//        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

Comment: About data save. In play: method  you not allocate memory. This means you cant save any data.

Comment: Method [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: return back like NSDictioanry. Just parse it in your model classes.

Comment: i hope it help :) And read about REST http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Comment: That was VERY informative :). I commented those two lines and I was able to see the data in the console. Thank you! I certainly need to read more about REST:) Quick clarification about the data save. In play action, you are basically saying that I need to allocate strings as well, am I right? And as a last question: Is this the right way of doing this?

Comment: >that I need to allocate strings as well, am I right? 
Yes.
>And as a last question: Is this the right way of doing this?
look at https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit it's solved all your questions :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38707/discussion-between-mett-and-bimawa)